# Github Host key verification Failing

Tags: docker, dockerfile, openssh

I am trying to add Github.com as known_hosts file for this docker file but somehow I believe www-data is failing to get access to known_hosts file. Code below is the complete docker file. Specific git error is

> Failed to execute git clone --mirror --

> Host key verification failed.
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights.
>
> and the repository exists.

```
   FROM php:7.4-fpm as base
    ENV COMPOSER_HOME=/tmp/composer
    ENV APCU_VERSION=5.1.18
    
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gnupg \
        netcat \
        sudo \
        libicu-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libsodium-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libxslt-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        rsync \
        unzip \
        git \
        openssh-client \
        ;
    
    RUN pecl install apcu-${APCU_VERSION}
    
    RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
    RUN docker-php-ext-install -j "$(nproc)" \
        bcmath \
        gd \
        intl \
        mysqli \
        opcache \
        pdo_mysql \
        sockets \
        soap \
        xsl \
        zip \
        ;
    
    RUN docker-php-ext-enable apcu
    
    RUN echo "memory_limit=1G" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-memory-limit-php.ini
    RUN echo "apc.enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-apcu.ini
    RUN echo "apc.enable_cli=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-apcu.ini
    RUN echo "opcache.memory_consumption=512MB" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-opcache.conf
    RUN echo "opcache.max_accelerated_files=60000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-opcache.conf
    RUN echo "opcache.consistency_checks=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-opcache.conf
    RUN echo "opcache.validate_timestamps=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-opcache.conf
    RUN echo "opcache.enable_cli=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-opcache.conf
    
    
    FROM base as build
    
    RUN curl https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar -o /usr/local/bin/magerun \
        && chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/magerun
    RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
        chmod 0700 /root/.ssh && \
        ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
    USER www-data
    WORKDIR /var/www/html
    
    ARG COMPOSER_AUTH
    
    COPY --from=composer:2 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
    
    COPY --chown=www-data composer.json composer.json
    COPY --chown=www-data composer.lock composer.lock
    
    RUN php -d memory_limit=2G $(which composer) install --no-progress --no-dev
    
    COPY --chown=www-data app/etc/config.php app/etc/config.php
    
    COPY --chown=www-data bin bin
    
    FROM build as app
    
    ENV MAGE_MODE=production
    RUN php -d memory_limit=2G bin/magento setup:di:compile
    RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize --apcu
    RUN php -d memory_limit=2G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
    RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/var/cache
    RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/var/page_cache
    RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/var/session
    
    COPY --chown=www-data app/etc/env.docker.php app/etc/env.php
```

Comment: Can you make it use HTTPS instead of git+ssh? Simpler.

Answer (score 1):

ssh will verify the key of the other server. It cannot confirm that the key presented by the server is trusted, so it fails.

```sh
ssh-keygen -R domain.com

ssh-keyscan -t rsa domain.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

```
The authenticity of host 'domain.com (a.b.c.d)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is XX:XX:...:XX.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

A: yes

Answer (score 0):

Please contact your system administrator. Add correct host key in /home/user01/. ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).